# How to add vue.js component multiple times @click?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue and have been trying to figure this out for days without finding a solution that works...
How do I add an external vue-component multiple times @click on button?
Hopefully my pseudo-code below will explain what i'm trying to do.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Piece/>
    <!-- HERE I WANT TO ADD MULTIPLE "<Piece/>" @click on below button -->
    <button type="button" @click="addPiece">Add Piece</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Piece from "@/components/Piece.vue";

export default {
  name: "PiecesModal",
  components: {
    Piece,
  },
  methods: {
    addPiece () {
      this.components.push(Piece)
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is "data driven"

Instead of wasting time "figuring this out for days", just read the excellent docs, [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) in this case...

```js
const piece = Vue.component('Piece', {
  props: ['number'],
  template: `<div> Piece {{ number }} </div>`
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { piece },
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
      pieces: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPiece() {
      this.pieces.push(this.counter)
      this.counter++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="addPiece">Add Piece</button>
  <hr>
  <Piece v-for="piece in pieces" :key="piece" :number="piece"/>
</div>
```